# remove all checked items from multi checkbox

Tags: jquery

Im trying to remove all checked items where checkbox name is qID5

MY JQUERY

```
if(value == 184){
   var $radios = $('input:checkbox[name=qID5[]]');

   $("input:checkbox[name=qID5[]]").removeAttr("checked");
```

//  I have qID6 and qID7 and this line is removing attr check from all of them not just qID5?

```
   $radios.filter('[value=232]').attr('checked', true);
   $radios.filter('[value=232]').parent().show();
}else{
   var $radios = $('input:checkbox[name=qID5[]]');
   $radios.filter('[value=232]').attr('checked', false);
   $radios.filter('[value=232]').parent().hide();
}}
```

MY HTML

```
<p><input type="checkbox" name="qID5[]" class="required" value="185"  /> - Play </p>

<p><input type="checkbox" name="qID5[]" class="required" value="186" /> - Musical </p>

<p><input type="checkbox" name="qID5[]" class="required" value="187"  /> - Tribute show </p>

<p><input type="checkbox" name="qID5[]" class="required" value="188"  /> - Concert </p>

<p><input type="checkbox" name="qID5[]" class="required" value="189"  /> - Stand-up Comedy </p>

<p><input type="checkbox" name="qID5[]" class="required" value="190"  /> - Youth Production </p>

<p><input type="checkbox" name="qID5[]" class="required" value="191"  /> - Meeting </p>

<p><input type="checkbox" name="qID5[]" class="required" value="192"  /> - Fundraiser </p>

<p><input type="checkbox" name="qID5[]" class="required" value="193"  /> - Other special event </p>

<p><input type="checkbox" name="qID5[]" class="required" value="232"  /> - Answered NO to question 4 </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`checked` is a binary property, not an attribute. You should also quote the name when it contains square brackets.

You need to use this to check them:

```
$("input[name='qID5[]']").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

or this to uncheck

```
$("input[name='qID5[]']").removeAttr("checked");
```